# Classpath: not working in @TestPropertySource within Spock Integration Test

Tags: java, spring-boot, integration-testing, spock

I have a Spock integration test which I am using to test a class that loads some files from a specific directory. MyClass uses a @Value annotation for locating files to load:

```
@Value("${data.directory.path}")
String dataDirectoryPath;
```

In the test I am trying to include the test data inside the classpath and was hoping to override the property that indicates where the directory resides.

```
@SpringBootTest
@TestPropertySource(
    properties = "data.directory.path=classpath:/test-data"
)
```

Running my test I can see the property in my yml file has indeed been overridden but the new value is: 'classpath:/test-data'. **Edit**: I was expecting the value to be an absolute path with the classpath transformed.

I've been trying to understand if this is a Spock problem or a Spring/Boot issue. As far as I can tell, @SpringBootTest should create a [ResourceLoader](https://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/3.2.x/spring-framework-reference/html/resources.html#resources-resourceloader) as part of it's context initialisation, but the resource loader doesn't seem to be doing it's thing with the 'classpath:' prefix.

Has anyone done this or knows what might be wrong?

For the moment I added a method on my class which allows directly setting the path to use. Then I can use the following in my test:

```
def sut = new MyClass()

def "setup"() {
    sut.setDataPath(Paths.get(getClass().getResource("/test-data").toURI()).toString())
}
```

Comment: What did you expect to be inside `dataDirectoryPath` other than `classpath:/test-data`?

Comment: @LeonardBrünings I expected it to have an absolute path to the directory. I thought the classpath: would be transformed. Maybe that's just not how it works though

Comment: Try using (Resource)[http://docs.spring.io/spring-framework/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/core/io/Resource.html] instead of String.